# Excel - how to display sum of different values in one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: Picture]

[image]

I'm facing an issue in excel ..

as attached in the photo i have the formula which works for one value only as following

```
=IF('Conformance Report'!G84="Finding (Not Documented, Not Implemented)";'Conformance Report'!B84;"")
```

but when I did it for a range of cells for example

```
=IF('Conformance Report'!G84:G353="Finding (Not Documented, Not Implemented)";'Conformance Report'!B84:B353;"")
```

it appeared as a (#value)

I need `B84` & `B85` (first picture) to appear in `F8` (second picture) when ever I choose "Finding (Documented, Not Implemented)"

Comment: What version of Excel are you using ??

Comment: Im using Excel 2010

Comment: how do you expect a range of cells to equal 1 value ? do you want it one cell in the range equal the value then do something, or do all the cells in the range need to equal a value to do something ?

Comment: Hi Peter, I've posted the pictures above now .. I need B84 & B85 (first picture) to appear in F8 (second picture) when ever i choose "Finding (Documented, Not Implemented)" G84 & G85 .. I need it for a range of data not only one

Comment: this can be done with `TEXTJOIN` in Excel 365, however there is no such function in earlier versions. You could use a macro e.g. like this: https://www.howtoexcel.org/vba/how-to-conditionally-concatenate-a-range/

Comment: Are you looking for the [CONCAT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/combine-text-from-two-or-more-cells-into-one-cell-81ba0946-ce78-42ed-b3c3-21340eb164a6)?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `SUM`. You're looking for an array formula using `INDEX MATCH` to return multiple results. Using those search terms on this site should get you the answers you need.